# Apache Wildcard Vhost not working

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain, namevirtualhost

I can't seem to get a wildcard vhost working on my local apache installation. My vhosts file currently has the contents below. After I edit it, I'm making sure to restart the server but have still had no luck getting it to work.

Basically, I'm trying to get *.joshholat.local to point to somewhere different than joshholat.local just to make sure the config is working.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jholat@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/www"
    ServerName joshholat.local
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jholat@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/www/phpmyadmin"
    ServerName joshholat.local
    ServerAlias *.joshholat.local
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have two virtual hosts with the same `ServerName` directive

Change

```
    ServerName joshholat.local
```

in the second vhost to

```
    ServerName www.joshholat.local
```

I would probably set different logfiles for each vhost also

So your config reads:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jholat@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/www"
    ServerName joshholat.local
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jholat@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/local/www/phpmyadmin"
    ServerName www.joshholat.local
    ServerAlias *.joshholat.local
    ErrorLog "logs/phpmyadmin_error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/phpmyadmin_access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still no luck. Is it because I'm on localhost and need to edit my hosts file? It currently has joshholat.local pointing to 127.0.0.1. Does that not get all subdomains as well?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to connect to whatever.joshholat.local? Do you have your DNS or hosts records in place? Try to ping www.joshholat.local

Comment: I think it is a hosts file issue. I added www.joshholat.local to the hosts file, and that now goes to the correct folder on my localhost. However, no wildcards on that domain are working (i.e. test.joshholat.local). I'm fairly certain it's because they aren't set to point to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file. And I don't think it's possible to set a wildcard in a hosts file, is it?

Comment: No that only works with DNS records, not hosts file entries :-) If you're not planning on using DNS you'll need to add all entries for subdomains of joshholat.local to the hosts file manually